# Sockets C server , android client

Tags: java, android, c, sockets

I got a problem with my server code. When i use this code it works fine
`message ="quit\n";`, but when i use `scanf("%s",message);`, it gives the error connection timed out by peer.

C server code:

```
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#define BUF_LEN 100

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    WSADATA wsa;
    SOCKET s , new_socket;
    struct sockaddr_in server , client;
    int c;
    int result;
    char message[BUF_LEN]; // if using message = "quit\n"; use char *message;
    scanf("%s",message);

    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2),&wsa) != 0)
    {
        printf("ERROR initlizaing winsock2 dll : %d",WSAGetLastError());
        return 1; // exit program with error.
    }

    printf("INitialised.\n");

    // create a socket
     s = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if(s == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        printf("error at creating socket :%d" ,WSAGetLastError());
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    printf("socket created");

    //Sockad_addr in strucsture prepare
    memset(&server, 0, sizeof server);
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    server.sin_port = htons(6000);

    // bind the socket

    if (bind(s , (struct sockaddr *)&server, sizeof(server)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        printf("Bind fialed with errror code : %d",WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(s);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }


    listen(s , 3);

    printf("waiting for incoming connections");
    // this part is what i dont understand.
    c = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
    new_socket = accept(s , (struct sockaddr *)&client,&c);
    if(new_socket == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        printf("accept fialed with error code : %d" ,WSAGetLastError());

        closesocket(s);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Connection acceptëd");
    //message ="quit\n";      // when i use this code it works fine 


        result = send(new_socket , message , strlen(message) , 0);
        if(result == SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            printf("send failed with error codfe %d\n",WSAGetLastError());

        }
        else{
            printf("sent %d bytes out of %u \n",result,strlen(message));
        }
    getchar();
    closesocket(s);
    WSACleanup();
    return 0;
}
```

Android java client:

```
public class Service extends Service{
    private boolean isRunning = false;
    private static final  String SERVER_IP = "192.168.178.11";
    private static final int SERVERPORT = 6000;
    private Socket socket;
    Thread ClientThread = null;
    String st = null;
    private Camera camera;


    public void onCreate() {

    }


    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId){
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

        // Annoucment about starting serivce

        // Start a Thread Called MyThread
        isRunning = true;
        this.ClientThread = new Thread(new ClientThread());
        this.ClientThread.start();

        // Keep running until it explicitly stopped.
        // stopped so returns sicky
        return START_STICKY;
    }
    // code


    public void onDestroy(){
        super.onDestroy();
        // stop background Thread
        isRunning = false;


    }

    public class ClientThread implements Runnable {
        public void run() {
            isRunning = true;

            {
            try{
                InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_IP);

                socket = new Socket(serverAddr,SERVERPORT);


                BufferedReader input =  new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));


                String st = input.readLine();

                if (st.equals("vibrate")){
                    Vibrator v = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
                    v.vibrate(1000);
                }
                else if(st.equals("quit")){
                    Vibrator b = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
                            b.vibrate(3000);
                }



                st = null;





            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    } 
}



    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's a lot of code to look through, if you could narrow down the problem a little bit that'd be great.

Comment: well if i use scanf my program dosent work , at the client it will say connection close by peer. when i use static char *message;   my program works  , so if i get user input it dosent work but a static message works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the problem:

You type: "blahblah" followed by the return key.

`scanf("%s", message)` copies all chars up to, but not including the \n char.  "blahblah" get copied into the message array. But the \n character is not copied into the message array.  "blahblah" gets sent.

\n is still left in the input buffer.

After the "send" call, your code calls getchar(). This consumes the \n char.

Then the server code closes the socket and exits.

The client, which is stuck on a "readLine" call, is still waiting for the \n char to arrive on the socket connection. But since the socket connection was closed by the server, readLine has to abort.

To fix this, either send a "\n" char after sending "message" or just insure that message has a trailing \n char appended to it prior to sending.

Example:

```
    strcat(message, "\n");
    result = send(new_socket , message , strlen(message) , 0);
```

Comment: would that explain the crashing of my server? application crash. cant test at this moment on school :/